# Send login packets to youtube

Tags: python, linux, git, github, youtube

I'm currenty trying to figure out how to send packets to youtube with login credentials. I have cloned a [git repository](https://github.com/Ethical-H4CK3R/YouTubeViews.git) to my kali linux machine. It 'visits' a web page with different proxy IP's. Those proxies come from the TorBrowser. It can visit a page, but it only counts as a view if logged into youtube. Is there any way i can possibly do this? Thanks in advance.

**NOTE:** The script works via packages. The browser isn't actively open.

Comment: To log into youtube.com you click the icon in the top right corner, select signin, enter your username and password then click submit.

Comment: It is not like that. The browser isn't actively open. The thing is it works via packages that the script sends to the youtube server.